# Compile program for ARM in Code Blocks on GNU/Linux

Tags: linux, gcc, arm

I try compile program for ARM - source code to dowload http://roboty.utp.edu.pl/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/minisumo_coide_v3.zip.
I use microprocesor STM32F103RBT6 (family ARM Cortex-M3).

I work on GNU/Linux Ubuntu 14.04 - my IDE is CodeBlocks 13.12
My compiler is 
arm-none-eabi-g   (GNU Tools for ARM Embedded Processors) 5.2.1 20151202 (release) [ARM/embedded-5-branch revision 231848]
Copyright (C) 2015 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
I downloaded it from https://launchpad.net/gcc-arm-embedded/ download

I set compiler flags
cortex-m3 processor [-mcpu=cortex-m3]

In other options is
-mcpu=cortex-m3 -mthumb

In defines are
STM32F10X_MD
STM32F103RB

I have problems because i work on GNU/Linux and all was prepared for Microsoft Windows 7 (Cocox IDE)
I dont know how to compile on Windows too and I thought on GNU/Linux will be easier and more cool hackers :)

I put build log

```
||=== Build: Release in minisumo (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler for ARM) ===|
stm_lib/src/misc.c||In function 'NVIC_PriorityGroupConfig':|
stm_lib/src/misc.c|99|warning: implicit declaration of function 'assert_param' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]|
stm_lib/src/stm32f10x_adc.c||In function 'ADC_DeInit':|
stm_lib/src/stm32f10x_adc.c|182|warning: implicit declaration of function 'assert_param' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]|
stm_lib/src/stm32f10x_dma.c||In function 'DMA_DeInit':|
stm_lib/src/stm32f10x_dma.c|111|warning: implicit declaration of function 'assert_param' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]|
stm_lib/src/stm32f10x_gpio.c||In function 'GPIO_DeInit':|
stm_lib/src/stm32f10x_gpio.c|111|warning: implicit declaration of function 'assert_param' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]|
stm_lib/src/stm32f10x_rcc.c||In function 'RCC_HSEConfig':|
stm_lib/src/stm32f10x_rcc.c|273|warning: implicit declaration of function 'assert_param' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]|
stm_lib/src/stm32f10x_tim.c||In function 'TIM_DeInit':|
stm_lib/src/stm32f10x_tim.c|125|warning: implicit declaration of function 'assert_param' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]|
stm_lib/src/stm32f10x_usart.c||In function 'USART_DeInit':|
stm_lib/src/stm32f10x_usart.c|133|warning: implicit declaration of function 'assert_param' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]|
sumolib/rprintf.c||In function 'rsscanf':|
sumolib/rprintf.c|398|warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]|
/home/szymon/Minisumo/gcc-arm-none-eabi-5_2-2015q4/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/5.2.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/lib/libc.a(lib_a-exit.o)||In function `exit':|
exit.c:(.text.exit 0x2c)||undefined reference to `_exit'|
obj/Release/cmsis_boot/startup/startup_stm32f10x_md.o||In function `zero_loop':|
startup_stm32f10x_md.c|| undefined reference to `_sdata'|
startup_stm32f10x_md.c|| undefined reference to `_sidata'|
startup_stm32f10x_md.c|| undefined reference to `_sbss'|
startup_stm32f10x_md.c|| undefined reference to `_ebss'|
obj/Release/stm_lib/src/misc.o||In function `NVIC_PriorityGroupConfig':|
misc.c|| undefined reference to `assert_param'|
obj/Release/stm_lib/src/misc.o||In function `NVIC_Init':|
misc.c|| undefined reference to `assert_param'|
misc.c|| undefined reference to `assert_param'|
misc.c|| undefined reference to `assert_param'|
obj/Release/stm_lib/src/misc.o||In function `NVIC_SetVectorTable':|
misc.c|| undefined reference to `assert_param'|
obj/Release/stm_lib/src/misc.o:misc.c|| more undefined references to `assert_param' follow|
||=== Build failed: 11 error(s), 8 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 3 second(s)) ===|
```

Can you tell what is resaon of my problems?

Comment: You're not including a header file that declares assert_param. You may also need to link against a library.

Comment: I haven't seen any file-library to link.
Where can be library to link?

Comment: You should `-DUSE_STDPERIPH_DRIVER -DUSE_FULL_ASSERT` and implement `void assert_failed(uint8_t* file, uint32_t line)` for the assert issue. The undefined references to `_sidata` etc., I'm stuck on that too.

Comment: I tried doing an arm compile in codeblocks. first it didn't detect the arm cross compiler. I entered the paths manually. Then it was spitting out linker errors for a missing configuration for build-id memory allocation. I added it. Then I got IRQ errors from the Vector.S file autogenerated by the project builder. I removed those symbols. Now I'm getting a series of undefined function references that I can't find anywhere in the project. Someone needs to fix 'arm' in codeblocks!

Comment: btw, it compiles just fine on the command line with no fancy parameters or include files and executes without a fuss on my pi.